# Save values of application for different projects

Tags: c#

I've created a program which calculates various naval stuff. Now is the time to save the users input, the calculations and the outcomes. Thing is, my colleagues need to calculate for different clients, for which they create different project-numbers. So I want to save all the values of my program, for these various projects. I will show the projects as start screen, in a `DataGridView`. Based on the selected item, the program must load the values.

I've taken a look at a previous solution from someone else, using a database for this, but my question is: is there anyway to do this, without the use of a database. Because I'm new to databases and not so experienced in C# as well. So if anyone has a tip, reference or small example, I appreciate it.

Some info about the application:

The application has different tab-pages. In each tab-page the user has to give some input, for example breadth, height, depth, etc. In one tab, the forces of wind are applied to the input on other tabs. In an other tab, the forces of lines are applied to several inputs on the different tabs, etc.

These values need to be calculated for different clients, thus different projects. These projects need to be saved, so they can be reviewed, edited, what ever. So, a person opens the program and sees a window with the DataGridView, which holds the different projects (project-number, client-name, etc). He clicks on a project to edit it, so he should see the values that belong to that program. If he closes this project, the values should be saved, and the user should be possible to select an other item in the DataGridView and load the values for the other project.

My question is: How do I save these "different projects" with their values.

Comment: Store them in a text file and read them when you need.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If this application only going to generate the values, if thats the case, just generate a file depending on the number of files a comma seperated file should be easy enough for your skill level.

Comment: @Ramhound I added some info about the program, hoping it makes it more clear.

Comment: @FJPoort - What is wrong with a csv file?

Comment: @Ramhound I implemented it now as a small test, but it would mean that I have to write over 50 columns with data. Will it still work?

Comment: @FJPoort - You tell us?  We can't tell you if an implementation will or will not work.

Comment: @Ramhound Turns out that the best way for storing data for different projectnumbers is in a database, so I have to dig in to that. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!